# How to repeat the whole code

Tags: c#, repeat

i would like to repeat the whole code but like you see it is going to end after the first one (sorry it is in dutch)

```
int nummervanappels;
Console.Write ("hoeveel appels zijn er :");
nummervanappels = Convert.ToInt16 (Console.ReadLine());
if (nummervanappels == 15) {
    Console.WriteLine ("goedzo, er zijn " + nummervanappels + " appels");
}
while (nummervanappels > 15) { 
    Console.WriteLine ("dat zijn er te veel");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Console.WriteLine ("raad opnieuw");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    nummervanappels = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());


}
while (nummervanappels < 15) {
    Console.WriteLine ("dat zijn er te weinig");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep (2000);
    Console.WriteLine ("raad opnieuw");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep (2000);
    nummervanappels = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
}

Console.ReadKey ();
```

I hope that you guys can help me.

Comment: Put it in a loop? I'm not sure what the question is here...

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "it is going to end after the first one"?
Can you show us a log of what you input and what you saw as outpup?

Comment: Maybe one `while(nummervanappels != 15)` and use an `if` statement to write out if it is less than or greater than 15.

Comment: You need a single while loop in which you do your work... what you have now is several while loops which are not logical.

Comment: Leuk school opdrachtje?

Comment: Nee gewoon voor de verveling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want.

```
Console.Write ("hoeveel appels zijn er :");
int nummervanappels = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
while (nummervanappels != 15) 
{ 
    if(nummervanappels > 15)
        Console.WriteLine("dat zijn er te veel");
    else 
        Console.WriteLine("dat zijn er te weinig");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Console.WriteLine ("raad opnieuw");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    nummervanappels = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}

Console.WriteLine ("goedzo, er zijn " + nummervanappels + " appels");
Console.ReadKey ();
```

One `while` loop until the user enters 15 with an `if` to tell them if they are too high or too low.  Then the statement about the correct number at the end.  I'm not sure why you have those 2 second sleeps, but I left them in there.

Also you could change the `if`-`else` to just

```
Console.WriteLine("dat zijn er te " + nummervanappels > 15 ? "veel" : "weinig");
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want this

```
}
    while (nummervanappels != 15) {
        Console.WriteLine ("dat zijn er te weinig");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep (2000);
        Console.WriteLine ("raad opnieuw");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep (2000);
        nummervanappels = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
    }
```